# Pattern Matching on Case Class With Option Fields

Tags: scala

I have a case class like this:

```scala
case class Foo(a : Option[String], b : Option[String])
```

and I want to pattern match on it to see if the values are present in the fields or not. What is the best way to do this?

I did the following but it doesn't work because it is thinking I am trying to create an instance of Foo:

```scala
val ff = Foo(Some("a"), None)

//psuedo code
ff match {
case Foo(a, b) => do something // all values present
case Foo(None, None) => error
```

Comment: `Foo(a, b)` will match any kind of `Foo` because you are not putting any restriction to their component, also remember `macth` works like an iteration, it checks each case one by one, it does not magically know to which case it should go. Thus, always more general cases should be last and more specific should be first. - maybe you wanted this instead `ff match { case Foo(Some(a), Some(b)) => do something with a & b ; case _ => error }` _(you can format this better on code)_.

Comment: Yes I got it work now as in your suggestion - thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

```
  case class Foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String])

  val ff = Foo(Some("a"), None)

  //psuedo code
  ff match {
    case Foo(Some(a), Some(b)) => // when both a and b present
    case Foo(Some(a), None)    => // when only a present
    case Foo(None, Some(b))    => // when only b present
    case Foo(None, None)       => // when both a and b are not present
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`case Foo(a,b)` will match any `Foo(Option, Option)` since you are not matching on an instance of `Option`. e.g. `Some` or `None`.

See Luis's comment above too.

```
scala> ff match{
     | case Foo(None, None) => "nn"
     | case Foo(None, Some(a)) => "ns"
     | case Foo(Some(a), None) => "sn"
     | case Foo(Some(a), Some(b)) => "ss"
     | }
res4: String = sn
```